# Is there a program to tell me if a specific parts list is available in a given colour?

Tags: inventory

I want to build some models using the new 1x2 curved slopes which come in limited colours at the moment, the models need to have single solid colours if at all possible.

Is there a program or site that will let me put in the parts needed and preferred colour, and then tell me if they are all available in that colour?

I know about Bricklink and Brickset (but not a registered user of either), so I can do it part by part if I need to.  I could also use LDD Manager to get a list of buyable bricks from a LDD file containing all bricks in all colours, although I would still need to check another site to find out what sets they are in.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: So, specifically, you're looking for a way to automatically look up part+colour existence for a list of parts?

Comment: Yes, and also the sets that I would have to buy if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're up for a bit of programming, [Rebrickable.com](http://rebrickable.com/api/#get_part_sets) has an API that can query part+colour and return matching sets.

> Get Part Sets
>
> Use this service to get a list of all sets that a specific part/color combination appears in. This is best used after calling the get_part function to retrieve the list of available colors.
>
> URL    /api/get_part_sets
>
> Method    GET
>
> Parameters    key - API Key
>
> part_id - The Part ID to look up (e.g. 3001)
>
> color_id - The LDRAW based Color ID to look up (e.g. 0 = black)
>
> format - How to display output data. Valid values: xml, json
>
> Returns   INVALIDKEY - The API Key is invalid
>
> NOPART - The part/color could not be found or has no sets
>
> Output data.

Comment: This looks interesting, I would have to learn how to program with a website API, but I'm sure I con do that if I find some tutorial sites.

Comment: @Windfire Here is something to get you started. You'll need an API key from rebrickable. http://jsfiddle.net/a1j39rtx/

Comment: That could help...